# app delegate's applicationWillTerminate not called when user kills app or shuts down device

Tags: ios

I need to know when my app is being terminated (I am not talking about going to background).

Unfortunately the applicationWillTerminate method is never called.

I found some posts on SO about applications going to background, but I really need it when they are terminated. (Pressing home-button twice and then swiping up)

Any ideas how to get notified, when the app is terminated?

Answer (score 3):

When the app is killed you will not get any notification to handle it in your app. The app just gets a signal 9, and the kernel cleans up the process including all threads.

I'm developing iOS-apps for almost two years, and I often have put a breakpoint into the `-applicationWillTerminate:` method, and the debugger never happened to break there. I think the method is only relevant to apps that are not multitasking-enabled - not multitasking-enabled apps are pretty rare since iOS 5. You'd have to explicitly disable multitasking in your Info.plist file, and there is usually no good reason to do this!

Comment: The method is actually called sometimes. But in case the app receives signal 9 your right.

Comment: @NilsZiehn yeah, I think it is called if the system terminates the application as a result of a low memory condition, or if it gets terminated because it uses too many resources in background. Anyway, you cannot rely on it getting called, so I think it's not really useful anymore. Unfortunately.

Comment: Any idea which signal is called when the iPhone is shutting down?

Comment: I assume signal 9. But you could test it. Override a few signal handlers (TERM seams most likely), override -applicationWillTerminate:, and log to a file. Make sure to flush or close after writing. Then shut down the device. I think the file will be empty still... you may open the file in mode "a" and use [my MPLog library](https://github.com/michaelpeternell/MPLog) for this. It flushes the logs to disk after each log line, and it can also tell you in which thread you currently are.

Comment: I just tested it with debugger running and it looks like its SIGKILL (at least thats what xcode tells me..) . That means no cooky for me :(